# implementing comparison operator in up-bottom parsing grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar

i have this grammar for implement four main operator in math `( + - / * )`
.

```
E --> E + T | E - T | T
T --> T * G | T / G | G
G --> id | no | (E)
```

and now my master ask me to change this grammar such that we can use comparison operator .
I think and just add this line to first of grammar  :

```
E' --> E > E | E < E | E >= E | E <= E | E == E
```

is this way proper?

Comment: I think you can answer the question yourself.  Given your changes, what would a parse tree for  x+5 >= y look like? Do you think that parse tree looks right?

Comment: i draw parse tree for your expression and i don't see any problem in it , is this grammar have problem ? @IraBaxter